# Partial Curl transition for modal seque in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I created simple app with two VCs.
I open second VC from first via button. Seque is "Present Modally" and transition is "Partion Curl". This scheme works fine on iOS7, but on iOS8 first VC's view disappeares in the end of curl animation:
[image]

Comment: This still exists in iOS 10 (Xcode 8.3 beta). Changing transition to Flip Horizontal was my way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem. I saw it in Xcode 6 (beta 7) + iOS 8 (beta 5).  Still present in GM seed of both.

**iOS 7.1 Specifics:**

It is called a "partial curl" and on iOS 7 it displays as such (e.g. Partial - you can still see a portion of the originating view along the top of the window).  On iOS 7 - when you tap on this partially exposed, "original" view, the view unwindes back to the full window of the origional.

**iOS 8 Specifics:**

The segue does **NOT** leave any of the original showing. And **any tap, anywhere** on the window/screen, returns the originating view via an automatic unwind.  If you have a UITextField on the view, when you tap on it to enter a value … the originating view returns without triggering any of the associated UITextField methods. No keyboard is displayed, it simply unwinds to the originating view.

It appears to me, that touch definition associated with what should be a partially displayed corner of the original view is instead mis-defined as the entire window.

Of course, I'm very new to iOS programming, so my insight, if accurate, does not give me a clue as to how to workaround it! LOL  I'm hoping that someone out there will have the knowledge to at least provide a usable workaround.

Jim

P.S. I don't yet have enough reputation points to vote or comment, hence my answer that isn't an answer.

Comment: "any tap, anywhere" only in upper half of screen (in my case - on iPad mini retina)

Answer (score 3):

This is either a bug, or (IMHO) an indication from Apple that this ModalTransitionStyle is about to be deprecated. Since it is probably the last vestige of pseudomorphism, I think that's a safe bet that it is short for this world. I was debugging an issue for hours with regards to inconsistent touches on a modally presented viewcontroller, using this transition and pulling my hair out. I switched to another modal transition style and POOF - all issues caused by iOS8 are gone.

Keith

Comment: Apple is really not mentioning any deprecations of (partial) page curl effects at all. So it's an iOS 8 Bug for me ;-)
This really sucks.
Exactly same build works perfectly on iOS 7 but not on 8 -.-

Comment: I consider this a bug as well, but unfortunately it has gone unaddressed for some time and even after several updates to Xcode. So if it is a "bug" per se, then Apple appears to either be unaware, or unwilling to correct it for whatever reason. I'm curious if this problem is limited to storyboards or if manually invoking the segue also exhibits the behavior. I'll try experimenting with it when I get a chance, but if someone already has and can confirm...?

Comment: Nevermind. I tried invoking manually as well as trying to construct it outside of the storyboard, which does not work unless you intend to write your own transition effect (i.e. override "perform"). Seems like this defeats the point of using the canned segue in the first place. I guess for now we have to either recreate this effect manually, or redesign the app to present the target view controller some other way. I'm not seeing another work-around at this time nor any explanation as to why this now fails when it used to work just peachy.

Comment: This issue still exists in iOS 9 beta.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution to the this problem is.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [self.view gestureRecognizers])
    {

        if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UIGestureRecognizer class]])
        {

            [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Touching anywhere in the top half of screen, caused the modal to close (unwind). Changed the animation and the world was at peace again.

So, definitely a bug in iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a superview, which contains UIDismissCurlUpTapGestureRecognizer, of the view where you want to disable that gesture recognizer. For exapmle in my case:

**po self.view.superview?.superview?.superview?.gestureRecognizers**

▿ Optional>
  ▿ Some : 2 elements
    - [0] : ; target= <(action=handleNavigationTransition:, target=<*UINavigationInteractiveTransition 0x15826e2e0>)>>
    - [1] : <***UIDismissCurlUpTapGestureRecognizer**: 0x15838a2c0; state = Possible; view = ; target= <(action=_handleTapToDismissModalCurl:, target=)>>

So I removed that gesture recognizer, with this part of code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if (self.view.superview?.superview?.superview != nil){
        if (self.view.superview!.superview!.superview!.gestureRecognizers != nil){
            for gestureRecognizer in self.view.superview!.superview!.superview!.gestureRecognizers!{
                if (gestureRecognizer.isKindOfClass(UITapGestureRecognizer)){
                    self.view.superview!.superview!.superview!.removeGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Note: it is very important, that you do this in **viewDidAppear**, because view isn't aware of its superviews earlier in the load cycle.

Answer (score -3):

I too chased this BUG for days! It turns out you can still use Partial Curl successfully; the problem only appears if the ANIMATES box is checked. Un-check the ANIMATES box, and you are good to go!

Comment: If you do so, you simply don't have the curling animation anymore. So that defeats the whole point.