# Picker view closes view/segue on random scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I've got a perplexing problem. I have a pickerView that closes/dismisses the view uncommanded. I can scroll to some rows fine, but others will cause the view to segue to parent view. I have tried this with a storyboard and an xib with same results. Simplifying to a clean simple project works fine, and I cannot locate the issue.

I suspect something goes on with the View Controller I cannot identify because I notice a strange happening in Storyboard Custom Class. The VC is named 'PLChooser', put that name in the custom class and it gets changed in Outline view to 'Chooser'. Something fishy is happening here and I can't find it!

I would post all the code; however, as I say the same code in a simple project works fine. Here however, is the basic protocol routines:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [pickerArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSLog(@"row: %d %@",row,[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]);
    ChooserLabel.text = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];


}
```

Comment: If you can't find it, it's unlikely that we'll be able to help without having access to your project, especially if the problem is in the storyboard.

Comment: Problem solved, and due to an Apple Bug! darn the wasted days chasing this bug!

Comment: Problem results from using a Partial Curl transition with animation checked. Any other transition, or used without animation, and problem disappears. Others have encountered this same issue but I guess I wasn't good enough in my searches to have found the solution/AppleBug (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762353/partial-curl-transition-for-modal-seque-in-ios-8). I would make this question answered, but it no obvious way to do that is evident to me.