# Strange behaviour of Views

Tags: swift

I'm designing an app for IOs in Swift 4. 
Firs a login view appears and if you press the login button the following code will be executed:

```
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBar", bundle:nil)
    let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBar") as! UITabBarController
    resultViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .partialCurl
    self.present(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

If we go to the any view, for example 
[image: Settings View]
 you will see a table view with 3 sections, the content is static. When you press whenever (doesn't mind if its the cell to the tittle of the section) it goes back to the login page. This happens in all the pages linked at the TabBar when you Tapped the 2/3 first area (the 2 first sections more or less) of the screen. 
It seems that it's executing:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Why it is having that behaviour? How I can solve it?

Comment: is the behavior same after removing "resultViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .partialCurl"

Comment: If I remove that line that behaviour disappear. It seems to be that problem. But why?

Comment: If I change .partialCurl for .coverVertical (for example) it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This either seems to be a bug or expected behavior. Users have reported it from back in iOS 7.
It seem to me that apple has defaulted the animation to just view the content not interact with them.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25768677/2570153) is an answer discussing the same.

I would suggest you to make a custom logic.

Comment: I'm using iOS 11.4 and happens the same. Thanks you, anyway, I will change the animation, it's not important at all.